Rank of a matrix $A$
Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{24} \\
a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{24} & a_{34} \\
a_{14} & a_{24} & a_{34} & a_{44}
\end{pmatrix}$$
I want to calculate the rank of the matrix $A$. I somehow calculated it using row reduced echelon form, and it is coming out to be 3.
I was wondering if there is an easy way to calculate the rank of this type of matrix, but I was unable to do so.
I would also like to know if there is any generalization of this type of matrix.
Kindly help me. Thank you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix

The matrix $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 
\end{bmatrix}  $$ satisfies $\text{rank}(A)=2$, while the matrix
$$ B=\begin{bmatrix}
11 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 
\end{bmatrix}  $$ satisfies $\text{rank}(B)=3$. Thus, you can't determine the rank of a Hankel matrix just by knowing its order.

Ok sir.Thank you for your counter example.So each time i have to use row reduced echelon form?

@SandeepTiwari Kinda, but not really. If, for example, you calculate the determinant of the matrix, and it's not zero, then you know that it has the same rank as the order of the matrix, without the need to perform row reduction.

Is there any generalized result for determinant of Hankel matrix?

@SandeepTiwari Not in the sense of that given the order we can know the determinant (the examples I gave will illustrate that, namely, the matrices $A,B$ above).
